# Cannot run my template in .dbt extension in Oracle 12c DBCA

Tags: sql, oracle, format, oracle12c, dbca

The following is my template file "testing.dbt". I kept it under "`C:\app\ORCLUSER\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\assistants\dbca\templates`".

I'm trying to create it from Oracle 12c (Enterprise) DBCA. When I select create database and choose it. It says, the template file is in invalid template file and it is not in the expected mode. Please help me with this.

[Here](https://myte.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZwSiaZ8dIhVbnevAY6VFS5TirSXjKWs9pX) is the file.

Comment: Will be better to ask this question in [Database Administrators Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks you sir. I will aslo ask there.